# How is xaml control rendered in UWP application?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am new to UWP app development and want to understand how xaml control is rendered in the UWP application. Which is the class that implements the rendering logic? And is that code open source? Also, when I create a new custom control, do I need to take care of rendering myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is xaml control rendered in UWP application?

This is a big topic, for understanding this, we need to know UI Framework Layering.  Windows.UI.XAML-> Windows.UI.Composition-> DirectX Family.
Derive from official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/composition/visual-layer), *The Visual layer provides a high performance, retained-mode API for graphics, effects and animations, and is the foundation for all UI across Windows devices. You define your UI in a declarative manner and the Visual layer relies on graphics hardware acceleration to ensure your content, effects and animations are rendered in a smooth, glitch-free manner independent of the app's UI thread.*

> And is that code open source?

Currently, the UWP open source controls are [WinUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/#windows-ui-2-library). You could find the base custom control build logic.

> do I need to take care of rendering myself

The rendering is very low level, if you just custom control that inherit Control class, you have no need to care about the rendering process, you just need to build the interface in the target templated style. and add specific dependency property in the code behind. For more detail please refer to [Templated Control document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-control-templates).